# ofActionSuccessful Return True Even When Have Errors in Angular NGXS

Tags: angular, angular6, state-management, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I have a problem when i try to edit my user. I've decided to fetch again all the users after successfully updated it. However if there is an error i don't want the form to reset and the modal to disappear. My problem is when i try to update the user and it returns an error. The ofActionSuccessful is still triggering even when there is an error. Please see my code below.

> Component.ts

```
    onEditUser(form: FormGroup) {
        const formData = {
          id: form.value.id,
          name: form.value.name,
          email: form.value.email
        };
        console.log(formData);
        if (form.valid) {
          swal({
            title: 'Update',
            text: 'Are you sure you want to update changes?',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#0CC27E',
            cancelButtonColor: '#FF586B',
            confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success btn-raised mr-5',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-raised',
            buttonsStyling: false
          }).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.value) {
              this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(formData));
              this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(UpdateUser)).subscribe(() =>
                form.reset(),
                this.modalReference.close()
              );
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

> State.ts

```
@Action(UpdateUser)
      updateTodo({ getState }: StateContext<UserStateModel>, { payload }: UpdateUser) {
        return this.usersService.updateUser(payload).pipe(
          tap((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            const state = getState();
            this.store.dispatch(new GetUsers);
          }),
          catchError(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return throwError(err);
          })
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no connection between our update user call and ofActionSuccessful. You are always dispatching ofActionSuccessful action whenever swal promise resolves. You might have been trying to do the following.

```js
 if (form.valid) {
          swal({
            title: 'Update',
            text: 'Are you sure you want to update changes?',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#0CC27E',
            cancelButtonColor: '#FF586B',
            confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success btn-raised mr-5',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger btn-raised',
            buttonsStyling: false
          }).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.value) {
              this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(formData))
      --->>>        .subscribe((sucess) => {
               this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(UpdateUser)).subscribe(() =>
                form.reset(),
                this.modalReference.close()
              );
              });
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: Hi! So you can ignore the ofActionSuccessful since it is of no use. you can just do it like this?  if (result.value) {
          this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(formData)).subscribe((sucess) => {
            form.reset(),
            this.modalReference.close()
          });
        }

Comment: It’s up to you if you think it has no use then yea you can just do that but if you wanna do something on success action dispatch you can.

Answer (score 0):

this is to late but i want to give a suggestion try this.

```
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(formData));
this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(UpdateUser)).subcribe((res)=> {
// any thing you want to do
});
```